# Group by in impala on customer ID with different account number

Tags: impala

```
CUSTOMER_ID  ACCT_NUMBER    TAG
CUST_ID      ACCT_NO1       NPA
CUST_ID      ACCT_NO2       NPA
CUST_ID      ACCT_NO3
```

Table A has above mentioned data.

I need to tag 'NPA' across the new ACCT_NO3.

Conditions:

- first grouping the table A on basis of the cust_id.
- if the cust_id has two different acct numbers with 'NPA' tag then mark the 3rd one also as 'NPA'.

How can one do this in impala?

Comment: You mean, same account number for account id? So for your example, the tag should `not` be stamped with npa ?

Comment: Eg: Customer ID with 3 different account numbers. Out of these 2 account numbers have NPA tag across them. How to mark 3rd account number too with NPA tag.